# How to play custom sound file when user get push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have a sound file in the app bundle, i want to play that sound file when user will get push notification.

IS it possible in iOS if yes, then please suggest the way to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: FWIW ANY sound (system sounds or your very own made sound) other than *default* is considered a custom sound and MUST be manually added to AppBundle.

Answer (score 18):

To play this sound you must specify the filename of the sound in the notification payload. For example, lets say you've added a sound file named example.caf into your application, we can play this sound with the notification payload as below:

```
{
    aps =     
    {
        alert = "test example notification message";
        sound = "example.caf";
    };
}
```

Then the custom sound will play when your notification arrives.

Comment: but what if I have settings in app that should play specific file. I don't want to use aps to specify sound file name, but I want to use local settings when I received notification. For example I have settings screen where I specify needed sound and volume level. Then I guess we need to use @007 answer?

Comment: In that case you follow @007 answer.  just you need to change `NSURL *url = create path according to your selected sound file` when you select any sound file from your setting screen. But you can't sync you payload with your settings means your payload `sound = "example.caf"` will not change when you change you sound file from your app settings. you have to apply logic in your local to to fill-full your need.

Comment: ok thanks) so you mean if I will specify `sound = "example.caf"` in aps then app will play "example.caf" file even app setting has different.caf as a sound for notifiaction?

Comment: Where to add file in application?

Comment: Anywhere in your app bundle @dpaksoni

Answer (score 7):

Use this method in your app delegte class.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        NSLog(@"User Info : %@", [userInfo description]);

        NSLog(@"User Info Alert Message : %@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]);

        NSString *messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]];

        NSString *playSoundOnAlert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],playSoundOnAlert]];

        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [audioPlayer play];

    }


}
```

Comment: You have to be careful, because if your app gets killed/closed to don't receive this delegate method call anymore.

Comment: I have test this solution and it's not working ! you will hear the sound after you have clicked the push notification and after you'll here the default sound of iOS system. i've yet find a way to do it.  it's ONLY working if the app in the foreground.