# can we add a custom sound for notification in iOS apps, other then the default sound provided by the OS

Tags: ios, mobile

We have a scenario where we need to play a custom notification sound for an app which is different than the notification sounds provided by OS. Is it possible can we add a different sound other than the OS sounds to the app and also do we have any problem while app review if we use such sounds in the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179630/how-to-play-custom-sound-file-when-user-get-push-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, You can change the push notification sound.

When server sends the push notification, just add the sound file name in `JSON`payload.

Sample Push Payload:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Your friend needs your help.",
        "sound" : "sos.wav"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the above code we can add custom notification sound, will it be a problem while app publish if we use some sound which is not in system sounds.

Comment: NO. It won't. This option given by apple only. You can publish with custom sound